# EE Freeform {exp:email:contact_form} error

Tags: solspace-freeform, ee3

I downloaded Freeform from Solspace free version and with Expression Engine 3, when trying to submit the form I get this error. Email is not part of the form and I don't get why this is happening.

```
Error
The following tag has a syntax error:
{exp:email:contact_form}
Please correct the syntax in your template.
```

Form Code:

```
{exp:freeform:form collection="contact" return="contact/thanks"}
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Your Full Name"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" id="number" name="number" required placeholder="Phone Number"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <textarea id="user_message" name="user_message" required placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Message"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Any ideas? The strange thing is that when I check EE CP I get the emails there but don't get notification via email.

Comment: What version of freeform are you using? The parameter "collection" is not used in 5.x.  See upgrade guide: https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/upgrade_3.x-5.x/

Comment: This might be it. I'll check when I get home. Its the latest version that I use

Comment: Does your **contact/thanks** template maybe contain `{exp:email:contact_form}`?

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but it seems to be a possible buggy patch in Solspace code revolving the email validation. I am working on an EE3 project and keep seeing an error in which "check_email_contact_form". persists.

Answer (score 0):

The core version of EE3 does not include the email module. So the system doesn't recognize the tag and passes back an error.